# Why do I get an error, when I set the variable type is `Int` and put it into the array as an index?

Tags: python

Why do I get an error, when I set the variable type is `Int` and put it into the array as an index?

I used Class, so cur.position[0] is representing as cur[0].

```
    x0 = cur.position[0]
    y0 = cur.position[1]
    x1 = child.position[0]
    y1 = child.position[1]
   


if dx == 0 and grid[x0,y0 +((sy - 1)/2)] == 2 and grid[x0 - 1, y0 +((sy -1)/2)] ==2:
                return False
            y0 = y0 +sy
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Theta2.py", line 291, in <module>
    path = astar(maze, start, end)
  File "\Theta2.py", line 224, in astar
    if LineOfSight (current_node,child,maze):
  File "\Theta2.py", line 161, in LineOfSight
    print(grid[x0,y0+((sy - 1)/2)])    
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

So Why did I get this error?

Comment: As the error says, `x0,y0+((sy - 1)/2)` is a tuple and you're trying to look up the list `grid` with it.

Comment: 2D arrays are accessed with `[][]`, not a comma - `grid[x0][y0+((sy - 1)/2)]`.

Answer (score 0):

If grid is a 2D list, then accessing elements using `grid[a,b]` is not the correct way, you have to access elements using `grid[a][b]`